# Sitecore - Workbox security

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-workflow

In my Sitecore workbox, there are several workflow states being displayed. (Draft, Awaiting, Approved)
How can I restrict acess only to one/few(Draft) workflow states for a particular role (e.g. Junior Manager) in Sitecore?

(I m using v6.5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. To be able to see the various workflow states you'll need read access to that workflow state as well as write access to the item you want to approve/ reject.

From the [Workflow Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/workflow_cookbook_a4.pdf) (chapter 3.1 and 3.2):

> 3.1
> The Content Editor and Workbox only displays workflow commands for
>   non-Administrator users  when: 
> The user has write access to the
>   associated item. 
> and The user has write access to the command’s parent
>   workflow state. 
> and The user has read access to the workflow command
>   itself.
>
> 3.2
>  Users who have read access to a workflow state can see that state in
>   their workbox as long as the  state includes workflow commands for
>   which they have command execute access rights. If business 
>   requirements state that a particular workflow state should be hidden
>   from a given set of users, you  can restrict access to that state for
>   those users by:
>  Hiding all the workflow commands in the state from the
>   users in question. 
> or
>  Explicitly hiding the workflow state itself from
>   the users in question. To explicitly hide a workflow state:
>  Turn off
>   the inheritance access right for the workflow state item and do not
>   grant read access  to the workflow state to the user and all the roles
>   assigned to the user. 
> or
>  Deny the user or one of the roles that the
>   user is assigned read access to the workflow state  item.